# Details of Activities and Resources in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to list all activities and resources in Moodle Course.. It should have details of ID, type, name and course id with name...
Someone would have created an adhoc query..
Can you someone help here please.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the activities per course but not the activity name

```
SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    cm.instance AS activityid, m.name AS activitytype
FROM mdl_course_modules cm
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cm.course
JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id = cm.module
ORDER BY c.fullname, m.name
```

For the activity name you will need to add the table for each activity in your site. So you will need to add to this list if you add new activities.

```
SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    cm.instance AS activityid, m.name AS activitytype,
    activity.activityname
FROM mdl_course_modules cm
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cm.course
JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id = cm.module
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, a.name AS activityname, 'scorm' AS activitytype
    FROM mdl_scorm a
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, a.name AS activityname, 'forum' AS activitytype
    FROM mdl_forum a
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, a.name AS activityname, 'label' AS activitytype
    FROM mdl_label a
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, a.name AS activityname, 'url' AS activitytype
    FROM mdl_url a
    ....
) activity ON activity.id = cm.instance AND activity.activitytype = m.name
ORDER BY c.fullname, m.name
```